# Where do limits come from?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Where do limits come from? Take for example :
$$
y = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}
$$
We say that $y$ equals $0$.

My question is, why does it equal to $0$? Is there a link with the definition of ${\bf R}$?

I mean, ${\bf R}$ can be viewed as the set of all the equivalent classes of Cauchy sequences which are converging. It means that $0$ itself is a set of all the Cauchy sequences converging to $0$. So, since $y$ converges to $0$ tightly as $x$ increases, maybe we can see it as a Cauchy sequence converging to $0$ ? And so we can add it to the equivalent class of $0$, which means that $y$ is actually $0$. Am I right or is it totally wrong ?

Comment: It is the limit of a function, not a Cauchy sequence. (if you used $n$ instead of $x$, then it would indeed be the limit of a Cauchy sequence.)

Comment: By $N,\varepsilon$ definition,$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L\iff\forall\varepsilon>0\exists N>0\forall n(n>N\implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon)$$

Comment: Simply Beautiful, but, this definition comes from topology doesn't it ? Why ? Why can we say that this definition is true ?

Comment: That's a definition, you don't need to verify it's true.

Comment: A definition is a definition. We don't say a definition is *right* or *wrong*. We don't say a definition is *true* or *false*. Take a look at [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-2-a-prime-number-It-seems-like-theres-something-fundamentally-wrong-with-the-definition-of-prime-since-2-is-the-only-even-number-included-Would-the-math-work-better-not-at-all-if-two-wasnt-on-the-list/answer/Alon-Amit?srid=tZT9).

Comment: To quote Wikipedia: "In mathematics, a **definition** is used to give a precise meaning to a new term, instead of describing a pre-existing term. Definitions and axioms are the basis on which all of mathematics is constructed."

Comment: This has nothing to do with construction of reals. The result holds if $x$ is rational or if $x$ is a positive integer. And it is an immediate consequence of the definition of limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking too hard (albeit thinking too hard *correctly*).

Let's not worry what the reals are because that's not entirely relevant. (Not *entirely*.)

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac 1x = 0$ is *not* saying that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac 1x$ is a number and the number is $0$. It is basically stating an observation:

The observation is:  For any number $\epsilon > 0$ we can find large $x$ so that $|\frac 1x - 0| < \epsilon$ and when we do, all $x$ equally large will have that conditions.  (or in formal math terms: There exist an $N_{\epsilon}$ so that for all $x > N_{\epsilon}$ we have $|\frac 1x - 0| < \epsilon$.

So limits don't "come from" anywhere.  They are just statements.

However it *is* part of the definition of Reals that we can often determine when these statements are possible.

The reals have the Least Upper Bound property. That means that if we have a Cauchy sequence it must have a limit (because for cauchy sequence $\{c_n\}$, the set $\{x|x < c_n; n>N\}$ will have a supremum $b_N$.  The set of supremums will have a supremum, $B$.  And the condition $\lim_{n\to \infty} c_n = B$ would be true.)

====

Oh.  I guess one thing that the makes it seem as though limits "come from" somewhere, would be that if the statements $\lim_{x\to \infty} f_x = k$ is true for some $k$ then it is only true for *that* value and it isn't true for any other.  That's a theorem and can be proven.

That is why we use the equal sign in the statement even though it isn't a statement about the value of any number.  That is also we can refer to the number, $k$, for which $\lim_{x\to \infty} f_x=k$ is true as $\lim_{x\to \infty} f_x$ as  "the limit" and assume it *is* a number.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of limits come from calculus, where we deal with infinitesimals. If I recall correctly it first turned up figuring out derivatives where the definition of a derivative is: $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \ \to \ 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

Here we have $h$ to be infinitesimally small and we then evaluate the derivative from that.

I can explain to you how at least I think about limits. Consider your expression: $$y = \lim_{x \ \to \ \infty}\frac{1}{x}$$

Now let's imagine that we start with $x = 10$, and increase it by a factor of $10$ each iteration (to *try* to reach the limit of the function, $\infty$):

$$y = \frac{1}{10} = 0.1$$
$$y = \frac{1}{100} = 0.01$$
$$y = \frac{1}{1000} = 0.001$$
$$y = \frac{1}{10000} = 0.0001$$
$$y = \frac{1}{100000} = 0.00001$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$y = \frac{1}{100000000...} = 0.00000000...$$

You can see what happens, when $x$ becomes extremely large, then $y$ becomes infinitesimally small, so as to not even exist because it's so small. Therefore if we take $\frac{1}{\infty}$, it's so small that we just defined it as $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Limits have a definition in real analysis. A sequence $y_n \rightarrow L$ if  for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for any $n >N , |y_n - L| < \epsilon $